# Загрузка multiple файлов на диск

Tags: php

```
$files = $_FILES['filesToUpload'];
echo $files;
if ($files) {
    foreach ($files['tmp_name'] as $k => $fileName) {
        $fileName = $files['name'][$k];  
        $path = '/public/materials' . $fileName;  
        $asd = move_uploaded_file($fileName, $path);
        if(!$asd) {
            echo "Error, while trying to save file<br>";
        }
    }
}
```

$files это массив, получаемый отсюда.

```
    <form method="post" action="upload-page.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
  <input type="submit" name="Stexelnkarnery.">
</form>
```

Получаю ошибку при загрузке файла, не могу понять в чем проблема.

Comment: Читайте логи сервера, там будет написано в чем проблема

Comment: Не нашел проблему )

Comment: Мы тоже без логов не найдём проблему

Comment: В одном из логов нашел что-то типа ошибки что сайз  очень большой, загуглил, но не разобрался как можно увеличить этот обьем " client_body_buffer_size " .